# ActionScript Negating a Number

Tags: actionscript-3, math

i'd like to negate a number and would like to know if there's a built in method that will convert a negative number to a positive OR a positive into a negative, depending on the number.

i know about Math.abs(), but that only seems to convert negative into positive.  is there a method that will do both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this as simple as multiplying by -1?

Comment: ah!  so it is!  LOL.  i guess that's a simple as any built in method could be.  thanks :)

Comment: Yeah you were totally overthinking it :)

Comment: but taking it as "-p" is better than doing "-1*p" for real; -p can be compiled into a single instruction that negates the variable (disregarding loading/storing instructions), while -1*p can get compiled into: load a constant, multiply the constant (-1) by p: 1 instr more and moreover multiplying can be slower, while negating is faster. (At least I hope that any reasonable VM has the negate instr on numbers both float and integer!)

Comment: Is it possible for some compilers to convert a "-1*" to the same as a unary negation operation?  Just a question I'd toss out there.

Comment: @JB King: Yes, any arithmetic operation to negate a number will be optomized by the compiler to be as fast as possible (flipping the sign bit).

Answer (score 4):

```
var mynum:Number = 5;
mynum = -mynum;
```

Other options include:

- `mynum*=-1;`
- `mynum = 0-mynum`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a method? Unary minus should do the trick as in many other languages! If `p` > 0,  `-p` < 0 and viceversa as we learned at school.